# ggplot scatterplot with missing x values, trendlines won't connect

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, trendline

I am new to R, and I'm trying to use ggplot2 to plot some data as a scatterplot. I'm missing a day in my samples, and the trendline I made won't connect all of the data together. Below is the code I have and what the graph looks like.

```
ggplot(SiExptTEPa, aes(x=Timepoint..dpi., y=(TEPcells),group=(Treatment))) +
    geom_point(size=5,aes(colour=Nutrient)) +
    scale_color_manual(values=c('yellow','light blue')) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=TEPcells-se, ymax=TEPcells+se), width=.1) +
    facet_wrap(~Nutrient, scales="free") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scientific) +
    theme_classic() +
    xlab("Time Post Infection (Days)") +
    ylab("TEP by Total Cells") +
    ylim(3e-08,2e-07) +
    geom_line(aes(linetype=Treatment)) +
    scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "dashed"))
```

[Incorrect graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Kow8.png)

Please tell me how to connect the gap in the middle of both sides of the graph so that there is one continuous line?

Comment: You probably get the warning `Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_point).` when running your code? Use `na.omit()` on your dataset beforehands. I tested your code with some dummy data and if you exclude missing values from your dataset, it works! E.g. `data <- na.omit(data)`

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: This worked, thank you so much! And I'll be sure to the next time I ask a question, thank you!